# ¿Por qué hay textos repetidos en Transifex?

Tags: soporte, traducciones, transifex

En Transifex, [algunas cadenas](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/40277878?key=0dd6b4f419f3489a580846fb4ebe831b) aparecen repetidas. ¿Por qué es esto?

Por ejemplo:

```
[$numVotes$ more votes needed] → [Se necesita $numVotes$ voto más]
[$numVotes$ more votes needed] → [Se necesitan $numVotes$ votos más]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5):

Una cosa divertida de los distintos idiomas, es cómo manejan la pluralización... En español, tenemos dos formas: singular (1) y plural (2+), pero en otros idiomas esto no es tan así (si mal no recuerdo, en ruso tienen 1, 2, 3, 3+.

El código de SOes es el mismo que el de SO, pero tenemos un sistema de traducciones (que levanta los textos de transifex) que se encarga de que el sitio aparezca (en su gran mayoría :P) en español.

Cuando un dev está trabajando en una vista, es su responsabilidad definir en función de qué valor hay que pluralizar una cadena... en este caso en particular, en nuestro código fuente aparece `_s("[#numVotes# more votes needed]", { numVotes: data.NewScore })`.

Esto quiere decir:

1. La cadena tiene una variable `numVotes`
2. Esa cadena va a ser llenada dinámicamente con el valor de `data.NewScore`
3. En transifex, hay que traducirla pluralizada (esto el desarrollador lo indica usando `#` como delimitadores de la variable en vez de `$`)

Cuando se hace un build en dev, parte del proceso es hacer push de las cadenas a transifex... y es ahí donde se generan las permutaciones pluralizadas (todos estos términos los estoy inventando yo).

Ahora, para poder traducirlas, es importante mirar las `Developer Notes` en el la pestaña `Context`:

[image: variant one]

esto quiere decir que, en este caso particular, hay que traducir la cadena **sabiendo que `numVotes` vale uno**. Por eso, la traducción correcta es `[Se necesita $numVotes$ voto más]`.

la otra cadena tiene `VARIANT: other`:

[image: variant other]

Esta cadena va a ser usada cuando `$numVotes` tenga un valor distinto a 1 (incluye el 0), por lo que la traducción correcta es `[Se necesitan $numVotes$ votos más]`.

Cuando las cadenas tienen más de una variable pluralizable, el sistema genera todas las permutaciones... por ejemplo, si en el código hubiera una cadena:

`@s("In #numYears# years, I should have changed jobs #numTimes#")`

esto va a generar 4 cadenas nuevas en transifex... acá van las variantes y las traducciones correctas:

- `numYears=one,numTimes=one`: En $numYears$ año, debería haber cambiado de trabajo $numTimes$ vez
- `numYears=one,numTimes=other`: En $numYears$ año, debería haber cambiado de trabajo $numTimes$ vec**es**
- `numYears=other,numTimes=one`: En $numYears$ año**s**, debería haber cambiado de trabajo $numTimes$ vez
- `numYears=other,numTimes=other`: En $numYears$ año**s**, debería haber cambiado de trabajo $numTimes$ vec**es**

Si tiene 3 variables se van a generar 8 y si tiene `n` variables se van a generar `2^n` permutaciones (en ruso, esto es peor... si hay 4 variantes por variable, ellos tienen `4^n`... whaaaaat!)

Comment: Interesante información. Es curioso ver que casi siempre todo tiene un porqué.

Comment: Mientras leía esta publicación en mi cabeza sonaba [esta canción](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyp7xt-ygy0)

Comment: La pluralización en ruso es el motivo por el cual [alexolut pidió que no se usen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/304899) más de 2 variables en una cadena, y cuenta que hay al menos una con 4 variables, que termina en 81 formas (3^4).